# empty jqgrid footer

Tags: json, jqgrid

im trying to display data on the footer in jqgrid, but it only displays the empty footer, no data.

Here are my jqgrid options:

```
jQuery('#backlog_list').jqGrid({
    url : '/tasks/backlog?format=json',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader: {
            root: "tasks.rows",
            repeatitems:false
    },
    colModel : columnModel.colModel,
    loadonce: false,
    sortable : function(permutation) { taskListConfigSerialise(); }, // re-order columns
    sortname: columnModel.currentSort.column,
    sortorder: columnModel.currentSort.order,

    caption: "Product Backlog",
    viewrecords: true,
    multiselect: false,

    onSelectRow: function(rowid, status) { selectRow(rowid); },
    onClickGroup: function(hid, collapsed) { saveCollapsedStateToLocalStorage(hid, collapsed) },
    resizeStop: function(newwidth, index) { taskListConfigSerialise(); },
    loadComplete: function(data) { restoreCollapsedState(); jQuery("#load_backlog_list").hide(); restorejqGridScrollPosition(); setRowReadStatus(data);},
    shrinkToFit: true,

    pager: '#backlog_pager',
    emptyrecords: 'No user stories found.',
    pgbuttons:false,
    pginput:false,
    rowNum:200,
    recordtext: '{2} user stories found.',

    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    userdata: "userdata",

    height: 300,
    width: 500,

    grouping: jQuery("#chngroup").val() != "clear",
    groupingView: {
       groupField: [jQuery("#chngroup").val()],
       groupColumnShow: [false]
    }
});
```

Here is the json:

```
{"tasks": {
    "records":"<%= @tasks.size %>",
    "rows": [
    "read":<%= readFlag.to_json.html_safe %>,
    "id":<%= task.task_num.to_json.html_safe %>,
    "summary":<%= h(task.name).to_json.html_safe %>, 
    "resolution":<%= task.status_type.to_json.html_safe %>,
    "points":<%= task.total_points.to_json.html_safe %>,
    "business_value":<%= task.business_value.to_json.to_i %>
     ],
    "userdata":{"points":"<%= total_time.to_json.html_safe %>"}
    }
   }
```

I checked firebug and the json is returning the userdata correctly with the corresponding value, also the data is loading correctly in the grid. I just cant get the footer to show the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoo don't posted the `colModel` which you use, but I suppose that it has `points` column. The problem in you data that you placed *all* JSON data inside of `tasks`. To be able to read `records` and `userdata` you should include the path to the properties in the `jsonReader`:

```
jsonReader: {
        root: "tasks.rows",
        records: "tasks.records",
        userdata: "tasks.userdata",
        repeatitems: false
}
```

What looks also strange is the value of array `"rows"`. If should be array of items. I hope that you have forgot to include additional `{}` inside of `[]` only during posting the information in the text of the question.

You should additionally remove non-existing jqGrid option `userdata: "userdata"` and can also remove parameters with default values (like `shrinkToFit: true`, `multiselect: false`, `loadonce: false`).

Comment: hey oleg, thanks a lot, i just added those 2 parameters to the json reader and worked perfectly, thank you